# Shortest path on a graph where distances change dynamically? (maximum energy path)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, landscape

I'm trying to find the shortest path between two maxima on a discrete energy landscape whereby the shortest path is that which *reduces the least in height* over the course of the total path.  Probably maximum energy path is more correct terminology, but in other words even if a path travels a long distance around the landscape but does not go down into the valleys it would be considered good.

My initial idea was to create a graph of the landscape whereby the weight was the difference in landscape height between neighbours, either positive of negative for ascent and descent respectively.  I have just realised that this will not give the result I need, and actually all paths between local maxima will have exactly the same cost.

I then realised that if the distance between nodes on this graph depended on the current position and history of the path, then I could get the result I need.  e.g. if the path has gone down and up from a valley, then I would assign no extra cost to going down another valley (as long as the path isn't exceeding lows it hasn't been to before).

**So are there graph search algorithms that exist where the the distance can change dynamically as paths are explored?**

**Or are there any other suggestions for attacking this problem?**

Comment: you specifically name valleys; what about mountains? Ie if a path goes down, but only because it has previously gone up, is this "sinking" considered bad as well? if so, I'd second Eiko's idea. if not, I'd think again ;)

Comment: A path can go down and up (and around of course), but because I am looking at paths between local maximima (or mountain peaks), by definition the path must go down at some point.  It is the extent by which it has to go down to reach the target maxima which can be considered the cost of the path which I am trying to minimise.

Comment: Are there any assumptions about the graph's topology, by any chance? Ideally, is it a (fine) rectangular grid?  I'm not sure how it would help yet, but it might.

Comment: No it is actually a combinatorial landscape of several 100 if not thousand dimensions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is known as the Bottleneck Shortest Path problem. It is in fact easier than the Shortest Path problem, and can be solved in linear time on undirected graphs. See for example [here](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/files/916/ZR-06-22.pdf).

Comment: Thanks.  I've been looking over this paper, I can't get my head around how they can modify the weights to make each one unique and still ensure finding the shortest path

Comment: @zenna: You just need to determine a unique ordering within all equally labeled edges while ensuring not to disturb other orderings. For example, if you have integer weights and 3 edges with weight 10, replace them by 10.1, 10.2, and 10.3. Then clearly for any path the bottleneck edge will be the same before and after the change.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented a version (not accounting for equal weights yet in python) http://pastebin.com/JKcMuWAn .  I have one more question: the paper states that the capacities (or edge weights) must be integral numbers.  I can't see how continuous numbers would affect this algorithm.   If it is indeed a restraint could I simply scale my current range (-1 to 1) to an integer scale (0 to integer MAX) for example?

Comment: @FalkHüffner  link has expired can someone provide fresh link for same source

Answer (score 2):

### Idea

I suggest an algorithm that builds an auxiliary tree (T) in which each node contains a list of vertices.  Each subtree will contain a set of vertices that are separated from the rest of the graph by a valley.  To find the distance between any two nodes, one would simply have to find their lowest common ancestor in the tree.

### Algorithm

Initialization:

1. Sort the vertices ascending by height (space: `O(V)`, time: `O(V log V)`)
2. Let T consist only of a root node `r`

`MakeTree(G, r)`:

1. Take the lowest vertex in the graph `G`, remove it from graph and add to the list in the root `r` (time cost per vertex: `O(1 + E/V)`)
2. Repeat the above step as long as the graph is connected
3. For each connected component `G'` of the graph `G`:

   1. create a new node `n` in T, attach the node as a child of the root
   2. recursively run `MakeTree(G', n)`

Now you've got a tree with such a property that if you want to go from vertex `A` to `B`, your maximum energy path will lead through the highest of the vertices stored in the lowest common ancestor of `A` and `B`.  In order to find the distance, simply find the lowest common ancestor and take the highest vertex `C` stored there and calculate `max(abs(h(A) - h(C)), abs(h(B) - h(C)))`.

### Example

Below is a sample graph and the corresponding tree (for the sake of brevity, vertex labels are their heights).  For example, if you want to go from 22 to 14, you have to pass through 10 (the highest vertex in the lowest common ancestor in the tree, distance = 22 - 10).  If you want to go from 22 to 20, you have to pass through 13 (distance = 22 - 13).

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following works:

Create a graph of the landscape with the weights being dist + abs(height_a - height_b).

The abs function makes it expensive to rise or fall, and as you already noticed, the height difference alone is not enough as it is constant for *any* two points on the map no matter which route you go.

The dist is the plain distance (or even a constant 1 in all cases) and might be omitted, but if you like to get *short* paths this should favor short over long with otherwise same costs.

It's untested of course. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Hmm I think I have confused some what, and maybe should rephrase.  I don't care about how far the path is around the landscape, I just want the path which reduces least in energy.  If we had just the absolute difference, it would cost alot to go up and down small bumps, which it shouldn't.  On the other hand if we only count descents, then we end up paying double for every valley (if that makes any sense).

Comment: How is going up and down 1 unit for 100 times costing more energy than going a 100 unit difference for 1 time? Physically the work would be equal. If it is not, model your weights accordingly.

Comment: Indeed going up and down 1 unit for 100 times should not cost more energy.  But if we use the absolute difference you will keep adding dist+(1) for every step you take on the path, that is unless I have misunderstood what you mean

Comment: Yes, as I said: it's just there to reduce the number of steps and you should feel free to leave this out - it's easy to make this ruin the whole algorithm.

Comment: sure you can leave out the dist, but I mean the terms inside abs() themselves will cause this extra expenditure in energy.  And if you don't mean leave out abs(h_a - h_b) then what is left?

Comment: No. They won't make up extra length. Again, 100 times "1 up" plus 100 times "1 down" = total "energy" of 200. Just the same as one big jump down of 100 and another jump up of 100.

Comment: yes, but the point is that in the former case I would want the cost to be 1, and in the latter case the cost to be 100

Comment: ah, so num sum, but max? Any priority-queue based shortest path algorithm should work, just don't add up the costs but use the max function instead and keep things ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Given the endpoints are at maxima, your problem is equivalent to this one:

For x in the graph, let h(x) be the distance below the starting point. (By the statement of the problem, all points are below the starting point).

Find the path which minimizes: max(h(x) for x in path).

You can use a variant of Dijkstra's shortest-path to solve this. I've copied and modified the description of the algorithm from wikipedia (only the distance calculation in step 3 changes).

1. Assign to every node a distance value. Set it to zero for our initial node and to infinity for all other nodes.
2. Mark all nodes as unvisited. Set initial node as current.
3. For current node, consider all its unvisited neighbors and calculate their tentative distance (from the initial node). For example, if current node (A) has distance of 6, and is connected to another node (B) with h(B) = 7, the distance to B through A will be max(6, 7) = 7. If this distance is less than the previously recorded distance (infinity in the beginning, zero for the initial node), overwrite the distance.
4. When we are done considering all neighbors of the current node, mark it as visited. A visited node will not be checked ever again; its distance recorded now is final and minimal.
   If all nodes have been visited, finish. Otherwise, set the unvisited node with the smallest distance (from the initial node) as the next "current node" and continue from step 3.

Comment: Actually, `min(h(x) for x in path` should be maximized.

Comment: This looks promising and has worked in a small text I made, and I believe it is max as he said not min.  Problem I have encountered so far is that I cannot stop prematurely when I have found the target unlike in a standard dijkstra.  Will report back

Comment: @Martijn I still think what I wrote is correct. min(h(x) for x in path) is always 0 (since the start point has h(x) = 0).

Comment: I think this is just confusion over the sign of h. I thought you meant that h(x) would be negative if x is below the maximum, but if you flip the sign, your formulation is of course correct.

Answer (score 1):

So you don't care at all about the total path length, right? Just the minimum value that you encounter along the path?

If that's the case, then you shouldn't use "distance" in the traditional sense as your cost for Dijkstra. Your priority queue should return the node with the highest energy value - that way you're guaranteed never to take a path through a lower value if a better path exists.

I believe this is different than what @Paul Hankin is suggesting in his answer. This will probably open a lot of nodes in the graph; I think you can optimize as follows:

1. Use the [Euclidean or Manhattan] distance to the goal as a the tie-breaker in the comparison function. That way, if two nodes have equal energy, you'll try the one that gets to the goal faster.
2. When adding nodes to the priority queue, instead of using its actual energy for its "cost", use the minimum of its energy and the smallest energy encountered so far. Since you only care about the global min cost, once you're forced to take a low energy node, everything higher than that "costs" the same. This makes the search behave like a normal A* search in the neighborhood of the goal.
3. Starting search at the lower of the local maxima (I'm not positive, but I think it will be faster).

Using the distance as a tie-breaker in #1 won't affect the minimum energy, but it should make things run faster (it's sort of like an A* search).

---

**Edit:** here's a completely different (but probably slower) way to think about.

First, pick a threshold energy. Do a standard Dijkstra/A* search, but reject any nodes whose energy is below the threshold. If you there is no path, pick a bigger threshold and try again. A "safe" initial guess would be the minimum E along a simple path (e.g. go left then go up) from the start to the goal.

Now increase the threshold, and redo Dijkstra/A*. Keep doing so until you can't find a path. The last path before you can no longer find a path is the shortest path that has the greatest minimum energy along the path.

You also might be able to reuse the path cost from one search as an improved A* heuristic for the next search. Since increasing the threshold will only increase the length of paths, it's an [admissible heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic).

---

Hope that helps. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Point 2 is not completely clear: you should use the 'minimal energy to reach a node', say E. The 'cost' of connecting a node to a visited node is the minimum of its own energy, and the value of E at the previous node.

Comment: @Martijn - I disagree (if my assumption at the start of my answer is correct). Consider the state of the search after it has crossed a "trough" and is near the goal. Since all nodes near the goal are greater than the value at the trough, the effective cost of each is zero, because none of them will reduce the global minimum along the path.

Comment: Right. That's what you get for defining non-local quantities as path lengths :).

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities.

a) In e.g. the version at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm there is a line that works out a possibly improved distance to a point v using a route through a point u:

alt := dist[u] + dist_between(u, v)

14              if alt < dist[v]:             // Relax (u,v,a)

15                  dist[v] := alt

16                  previous[v] := u

You seem to want a version that goes
alt := K - min(height[u], height[v]). This works for much the same reason as the version with addition: at any time the set of vertices removed from Q all have the minimum cost worked out correctly for any route from the source. Each time you remove a vertex from Q, because you are removing the one with minimum distance, there is no chance of any short cut to it using the other vertices still in Q.

b) Take any method for working out if there is a route at all from the source. Use a graph which contains only point with height >= H and see if there is a solution. Try various H until you find one that just works. You can sort all the heights ahead of time and then use binary chop on this array.